# Check which ImageView was clicked inside ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView which works with Custom-Item-Templates.

Inside the List-Item Template are ImageViews (used as Buttons) and several Strings. The Data is bound with CustomAdapter.

I want to to do specific things inside the ListView with each Item on clicking different ImageViews.

I come from .NET and WebDevelopment and very new in Android.

How can I achieve to check which Button or Image in which ListItem was clicked.

Normally i would give each element in ListItem custom attribute whith unique_id including a key from the DataItem and get that Key in a Click-Event of Buttom and so on.

Is there any opinion to give a ImageView a Custom Attribute like 'MyCustomID' and get that in the Click-Event from it? Or how is the usual workflow for a situation like this: ListItems with repeating Elements and checking what ListItem belongs to the clicked Element inside.

Please help!

Comment: as there is an answer, I can give a recommendation of good practices as you are new to android; use RecyclerView instead of ListView and ImageButton instead of ImageView as a button.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   //  position is the index of clicked item.
   
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, with this implementation every Element in the ListView fires that Event, isnt it? I want different Methods on differnt Elements inside the ListItem

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd recommend to change to RecyclerView. It is more performant, flexible and easier to use. [Here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=Cj0KCQjw8eOLBhC1ARIsAOzx5cF-YAIDAWj9jTIV-YE-TcDotObd_RpjirBBBCoZHVirUc4nC1UW8PEaAvj6EALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) you can check how to do it.

About your question: I don't remember exactly how to implement ListView, but I believe that you have an adapter. In that adapter, you are creating the view of your items. So, what you can do is create a listener interface that receives the info of your items. Something like:

```kotlin
interface OnImageItemClickListener {
    fun onImageClicked(imageInfo: ImageInfo)
}

data class ImageInfo(
    val id: Long,
    val uri: URI,
)
```

Then you can pass an implementation of that interface to your adapter, and then use it in the `View.setOnClickListener` method:

```kotlin
class CustomAdapter(
    private val listener: OnImageItemClickListener,
    private val info: List<ImageInfo>,
) : ... {
    override getView(position: Int, convertView: View, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        // Inflate your view...
        view.setOnClickListener {
            listener.onImageClicked(info[position])
        }
    }
}
```

Again, I highly recommend to migrate to RecyclerView. If you implement it, you'll have to follow the same steps.

Comment: Thank you for your Advice with the RecyclerView, I`m going to change this and try your approach